# Проблемы с версткой блока-описания

Tags: html, css

Добрый день, уважаемые пользователи StackOverflow.com! Появилась проблема, суть которой попытаюсь описать ниже. Заранее спасибо за советы и любую помощь...
По макету хотел сверстать этот блок (Скриншот места на макете). Но почти ничего толкового не вышло.

[image: Собственно скриншот макета]

Comment: В чем суть проблемы?

Comment: Хорошая проблема: "Нужно сверстать", и вот не менее хороший совет: "Вам помогут на любой бирже фриланса"

Comment: Судя по контексту, автор таки хотел описать, но "...тут внезапно постучали в дверь...©" Подождём...

Comment: @IgorTkachuk, суть в том, что при float нормально ничего не центрируется... И не обтекает должно...

Comment: макет у тебя адаптивен или фиксирован ?

Comment: @MaksDevda, фиксирован

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался с вопросом. Просто заключил окружность и текст в блок с высотой в 182px и шириной wrapper'a (960px).